# Virtual PC (XPMode) - How to access Webserver on guest from host

Tags: windows-7, webserver, virtual-pc

I have Windows XP running inside Windows 7 via Virtual PC (XPMode) and installed Zend Server CE on the virtual XP guest. The webserver is running and can be accessed on the guest, but I cannot access the webserver from the Win7 host.

I configured a static IP address and subnet of 255.255.255.0 on the guest and can ping this IP from the guest but not from the host. The other way it works fine, i.e. I can ping the host from the guest. I can also access the internet from the virtual XP guest.

I tried different Network Options in the VirtualPC settings, but nothing helps. Googling the topic I couldn't find anything helpful yet.

Any idea, what I could try to access the webserver on the virtual XP guest from the Win7 host?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got it running.

Here is what I did:

- VirtualPC => Settings => Network: Selected my WiFi Adapter instead of NAT
- Determined the IP address of the virtual XP guest with ipconfig.
- Accessed webserver on guest with browser on Win7 host by the determinded IP address.

Don't ask me why, but it didn't work with defining a static IP address on the guest, so I left it to dynamic. The ping command does not work either, so don't check access by pinging your guest, just test with your browser.

I dont't really know much about network configuration, so there might be a better solution :)